# How to query the same categories AVG value of recently updated date in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, average, greatest-n-per-group

Is that possible to do like below in a single query in Postgres?

Table: name

```
-------------------------------------
| id    | unique_name   | category  |
-------------------------------------
| 1     | A             | One       |
| 2     | B             | One       |
| 3     | C             | One       |
| 4     | D             | Two       |
| 5     | E             | Two       |
| 6     | F             | Two       |
| 7     | G             | Three     |
| 8     | H             | Three     |
-------------------------------------
```

Table: price

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id    | name_id       | amount    | updated_date  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1             | 4.3       | 20-06-2020    |
| 2     | 2             | 2.3       | 20-06-2020    |
| 3     | 2             | 2.4       | 18-06-2020    |
| 4     | 3             | 4.4       | 20-06-2020    |
| 5     | 3             | 6.3       | 15-06-2020    |
| 6     | 4             | 0.2       | 10-06-2020    |
| 7     | 4             | 0.3       | 15-06-2020    |
| 8     | 4             | 7.4       | 20-06-2020    |
| 9     | 5             | 3.4       | 20-06-2020    |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I have a table structure like above.

I want avg amount of the same category which is updated recently.

Something like below:

```
-----------------------------
| avg           | category  |
-----------------------------
| 3.66          | One       |     (4.3 + 2.3 + 4.4) / 3
| 5.4           | Two       |     (7.4 + 3.4) / 2
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Please defined "updated recently" In the last day? In the last week? In the last month?

Comment: I'm lost.  Where is category 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` to get the latest `price` row per `name_id`, then join the `name` table and aggregate:

```
select n.category, avg(p.price) avg_price
from name n
inner join (
    select distinct on(name_id) p.*
    from price p
    order by name_id, updated_at desc
) p on p.name_id = n.id
group by n.category
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average of prices on the *most recent date*, then you can use:

```
select n.category, avg(p.price)
from name n join
     price p
     on p.name_id = n.id
where p.updated_at = (select max(p2.updated_at) from price)
group by n.category;
```

This seems to be close to what you are asking for.

Comment: I think `aggregate functions (MAX)` are not allowed in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @upadhyas: it's not used in the WHERE clause it's used in the SELECT list of a sub-query used in the WHERE clause.